# Encoding Issues when reading R Object

Tags: r, character-encoding

I am reading an R object with the readRDS.  It should have two columns, a year and a character string.  For most rows, the character string is OK, but some have a strange white blob and others seem to have a character vector with escaped special characters and some have special characters like â.

I think its an encoding issue with the original data (which is not mine), but am unsure what the blobs are or what causes the character vectors / escaping.  I realise its probably the original data, but trying to understand a little more of what I am seeing so I can investigate.

I'm using macOS 10.14.6.

Any ideas welcome.

The original data is [here](https://zenodo.org/record/2537227#.Xwg4Li2ZPm0) and I used the following to pull out some of the rows with strange characters.

```
data <- readRDS("all_speech.rds") %>%
    select(year, speech) %>%
    filter(str_detect(speech, "â"))

str(hansardOrig)
'data.frame':   2286324 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ year  : num  1979 1979 1979 1979 1979 ...
 $ speech: chr  "Mr. Speaker ...
```

## Added

```
sample <- data %>% mutate(speech = substr(speech, 1, 200)) 
dput(head(sample))
structure(list(year = c(1982, 1982, 1982, 1984, 1986, 1986), 
    speech = c("With this it will be convenient to take amendment No. 112, in title, line 10, leave out 'section 163 1) ofâ€™.\n", 
    "I am not so much surprised as astonished by the amendment. It would create tremendous problems. Police officers have a vital role in visiting places of entertainment—without a warrant—particularly in ", 
    "I note the hon. Gentleman's desire to retire there.\nMy right hon. Friend mentioned that we are setting up a pilot scheme with three experimental homes. They will be in adapted, domestic-style, buildin", 
    "The British forces in the Lebanon had their headquarters at Haddâsse. From that position they would have been totally unable to help British nationals in west Beirut. They are better able to help, thr", 
    "We know that soon more cars will be manufactured in the United Kingdom, as the hon. Member for Edinburgh, Central Mr. Fletcher) wishes.\nhirdly, the decision will have a domino effect—that American phr", 
    "I beg to move,\nThat leave be given to bring in a Bill to make illegal the display of pictures of naked or partially naked women in sexually provocative poses in newspapers.\nThis is a simple but import"
    )), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image: data shown in Rstudio viewer]

Comment: That file is so big (3.1 GB) I don't want to download it.  Could you use `dput()` on the entries you're showing us, i.e. `dput(head(data))`?

Comment: @user2554330. The speeches are very long, so I've just included the first 200 characters.

Comment: Interestingly, if I google the 3rd line down relating to British Forces, an entry from the Margaret Thatcher Foundation (https://www.margaretthatcher.org/document/105619) comes up with the same form of Haddâsse used in the downloaded file (i.e. with the special â character).

Answer (score 1):

You've got a difficult problem ahead of you.  The sample you show has inconsistent encodings, so fixups will be hard to do.

The first entry in `sample$speech` displays like this on my Mac:

```
> sample$speech[1]
[1] "With this it will be convenient to take amendment No. 112, in title,
line 10, leave out 'section 163 1) ofâ€™.\n"
```

This looks okay up to the end, where the `â€™` characters look like a UTF-8 encoding for a directional quote `"’"`, interpreted in the WINDOWS-1252 encoding. I can fix that with this code:

```
> iconv(sample$speech[1], from="utf-8", to="WINDOWS-1252")
[1] "With this it will be convenient to take amendment No. 112, in title,
line 10, leave out 'section 163 1) of’.\n"
```

However, this messes up the second entry, because it has em-dashes correctly encoded, so the translation converts them to hex 97 characters, not legal in the native UTF-8 encoding on the Mac:

```
> sample$speech[2]
[1] "I am not so much surprised as astonished by the amendment. It would
create tremendous problems. Police officers have a vital role in visiting
places of entertainment—without a warrant—particularly in "
> iconv(sample$speech[2], from="utf-8", to="WINDOWS-1252")
[1] "I am not so much surprised as astonished by the amendment. It would
create tremendous problems. Police officers have a vital role in visiting
places of entertainment\x97without a warrant\x97particularly in "
```

There are functions in various packages to guess encodings and to fix them, e.g. `rvest::repair_encoding`, `stringi::stri_enc_detect`, but I couldn't get them to work on your data.  I wrote one myself, based on these ideas:  use `utf8ToInt` to convert each string to its Unicode code point, then look for which ones contain multiple high values in a sequence.  `sample$speech[1]` looks like this:

```
> utf8ToInt(sample$speech[1])
  [1]   87  105  116  104   32  116  104  105  115   32  105  116   32  119  105  108  108
 [18]   32   98  101   32   99  111  110  118  101  110  105  101  110  116   32  116  111
 [35]   32  116   97  107  101   32   97  109  101  110  100  109  101  110  116   32   78
 [52]  111   46   32   49   49   50   44   32  105  110   32  116  105  116  108  101   44
 [69]   32  108  105  110  101   32   49   48   44   32  108  101   97  118  101   32  111
 [86]  117  116   32   39  115  101   99  116  105  111  110   32   49   54   51   32   49
[103]   41   32  111  102  226 8364 8482   46   10
```

and that sequence near the end `226 8364 8482` is typical for a misinterpreted UTF-8 character.  (The Wikipedia page describes the encoding in detail.  Two byte chars start with 192 to 223, three byte chars start with 224 to 239, and four byte chars start with 240 to 247.  Chars after the first are all in the range 128 to 191.  The tricky part is figuring out how these high order chars will be displayed, because that depends on the wrongly assumed encoding.)  Here's a quick and dirty function that tries every encoding known to `iconv()` and reports on what it does:

```
fixEncoding <- function(s, guess = iconvlist()) {
  firstbytes <- list(as.raw(192:223), 
                     as.raw(224:239), as.raw(240:247))
  nextbytes <- as.raw(128:191)
  for (i in seq_along(s)) {
    str <- utf8ToInt(s[i])
    if (any(str > 127)) {
      fixes <- c()
      encs <- c()
      for (g in guess) {
        high <- which(str > 127)
        firsts <- lapply(firstbytes, function(s) utf8ToInt(iconv(rawToChar(s), from = g, to = "UTF-8", sub="")))
        nexts <- utf8ToInt(iconv(rawToChar(nextbytes), from = g, to = "UTF-8", sub = ""))
        for (try in 1:3) {
          starts <- high[str[high] %in% firsts[[try]]]
          starts <- starts[starts <= length(str) - try]
          for (hit in starts) {
            if (str[hit+1] %in% nexts &&
                (try < 2 || str[hit+2] %in% nexts) &&
                (try < 3 || str[hit+3] %in% nexts)) 
              high <- setdiff(high, c(hit, hit + 1, 
                                    if (try > 1) hit + 2, 
                                    if (try > 2) hit + 3))
          }
        }
        if (!length(high)) {
          fixes <- c(fixes, iconv(s[i], from = "UTF-8", to = g, mark = FALSE))
          encs <- c(encs, g)
        }
      }
      if (length(fixes)) {
        if (length(unique(fixes)) == 1) {
          s[i] <- fixes[1]
          message("Fixed s[", i, "] using one of ", paste(encs, collapse=","), "\n", sep = "")
        } else {
          warning("s[", i, "] has multiple possible fixes.")
          message("It could be")
          uniq <- unique(fixes)
          for (u in seq_along(uniq))
            message(paste(encs[fixes == uniq[u]], collapse = ","), "\n")
          message("Not fixed!\n")
        }
      }
    }
  }
  s
}
```

When I try it on your sample, I see this:

```
> fixed <- fixEncoding(sample$speech)
Fixed s[1] using one of CP1250,CP1252,CP1254,CP1256,CP1258,MS-ANSI,MS-ARAB,MS-EE,MS-TURK,WINDOWS-1250,WINDOWS-1252,WINDOWS-1254,WINDOWS-1256,WINDOWS-1258
```

You can make it less verbose by calling it as

```
fixed <- suppressMessages(fixEncoding(sample$speech))
```

The other issue you had in your original post was that some strings were being displayed as single characters.  I think that's an RStudio bug.  If I put too many characters in a single element in a dataframe, the RStudio viewer can't display it.  For me the limit is around 10240 chars.  This dataframe won't display properly:

```
d <- data.frame(x = paste(rep("a", 10241), collapse=""))
```

but any smaller number works.  This isn't an R issue; it can display that dataframe in the console with no problem.  It's only `View(d)` that is bad, and only in RStudio.

Comment: Edited to add the `fixEncoding()` function.

Comment: Gosh @user2554330, this is worse than I thought.  I'm going to go back to the original source of the data (not the one I'm using) to see if that is cleaner.  Thanks for your help and I'll let you know :)

Comment: I've gone back to the raw data and it looks better so far.  I'm still getting white blobs on some screens, do you know that they mean?  If I select and output that line, then it looks OK

Comment: I talked about the blobs in the last paragraph.  It's an RStudio bug.

Comment: Sorry, you did. Thank you.